# Consideraciones para usar libreria (PHPMailer) con licencia LGPL

Tags: php

¿Sabrán que tengo que considerar para usar la librería PHPMailer que esta bajo la licencia LGPL, en un sistema que se va comercializar? Lei la documentación de la licencia (http://gugs.sindominio.net/licencias/lgpl-es.html), pero me queda la duda si es suficiente incluir el archivo License para que pueda utilizar la librería en el proyecto que esta pensado comercializarse.
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Breve contestación:**

> Puedes usar la biblioteca `PHPMailer` libremente para tus proyectos
>   comerciales.

**Larga contestación:**

> La `LGPL` está pensada como una licencia para bibliotecas de software.
>
> La idea básica es que la biblioteca quede como software libre.
>
> Sin
>   embargo, **se puede utilizar en aplicaciones comerciales aunque no sea
>   libre de uso.**
>
> El código fuente de la biblioteca con licencia LGPL tiene que estar
>   disponible para los licenciatarios.

Comment: Bien entiendo, gracias aldanux.